# "ImportError: cannot import name 'ImmutableDict'" error when installing pgAdmin4

Tags: pgadmin, werkzeug

I am trying to install pgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 18.04 with python3 following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode) (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode) but when configuring pgAdmin4 I get this error:

```
(my_env) 1 jess@hilarioserver:~/environments$ python my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, \
  File "/home/cta/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from flask_babelex import Babel, gettext
  File "/home/cta/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_babelex/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from werkzeug import ImmutableDict
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImmutableDict'
```

I already tried to install werkzeug but still giving the same error.

> alembic (1.4.0) Babel (2.8.0) bcrypt (3.1.7) blinker (1.4) cffi
>   (1.13.2) Click (7.0) cryptography (2.8) Flask (1.0.2) Flask-BabelEx
>   (0.9.3) Flask-Compress (1.4.0) Flask-Gravatar (0.5.0) Flask-Login
>   (0.4.1) Flask-Mail (0.9.1) Flask-Migrate (2.4.0) Flask-Paranoid
>   (0.2.0) Flask-Principal (0.4.0) Flask-Security (3.0.0)
>   Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.3.2) Flask-WTF (0.14.2) itsdangerous (1.1.0)
>   Jinja2 (2.11.1) Mako (1.1.1) MarkupSafe (1.1.1) paramiko (2.7.1)
>   passlib (1.7.1) **pgadmin4 (4.18)** **pip (9.0.1)** pkg-resources (0.0.0)
>   psutil (5.5.1) psycopg2-binary (2.8.4) pycparser (2.19) PyNaCl (1.3.0)
>   python-dateutil (2.8.1) python-editor (1.0.4) pytz (2018.9) setuptools
>   (39.0.1) simplejson (3.16.0) six (1.14.0) speaklater (1.3) SQLAlchemy
>   (1.3.13) sqlparse (0.2.4) sshtunnel (0.1.5) **Werkzeug (1.0.0)** **wheel**
>   **(0.34.2)** WTForms (2.2.1)

Any idea?

Comment: I have updated `flask-babelex` to version `>=0.9.4` following this recommendation in [flask-babelex repository issues](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-babelex/issues/21#issuecomment-584695395).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been troubleshooting this today while installing another package as well and it seems there was a new version released today that might be causing the issue.

https://pypi.org/project/Werkzeug/#history

I decided to go back to an earlier version (0.16.1) and it solved my issue. To downgrade:

`pip install --upgrade werkzeug==0.16.1`

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 7):

The method of import has changed for v1.0.0. See this warning message:

```
The import 'werkzeug.ImmutableDict' is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 1.0. Use 'from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableDict' instead.
    from werkzeug import ImmutableDict
```

Answer (score 4):

upgrade to `flask-babelex>=0.9.4` (or `flask-babel>=1.0.0` for other projects) if other dependencies will allow it.
[flask-babelex Github issue 21](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-babelex/issues/21)
[flask-babel Github issue 162](https://github.com/python-babel/flask-babel/issues/162)

Answer (score 1):

from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableDict

Comment: Can you be more explicit and give a full example?